# A doubt about the heat equation solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation

I was watching to Professor Gilbert Strang solving the heat equation and I did not understand one point. Let me guide you to my thinking:

Starting with the 1D heat equation

$$ \frac{\partial T}{\partial t} = \gamma \cdot \frac{\partial^{2}T}{\partial x^{2}} $$

In order to solve this differential equation, we can say that T(t,x) is of the form

$$ T(t, x) = e^{\lambda t}S(x) $$

Where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue and $S(x)$ is the eigenfunction. Plugging this expression for T in the heat equation, we will be able to find what is the eigenfunction and then the eigenvalue.

$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(e^{\lambda t}S(x)) = \gamma \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{2}}(e^{\lambda t}S(x)) $$

$$ \lambda e^{\lambda t}S(x) = \gamma \cdot e^{\lambda t} \frac{\partial^{2} S(x)}{\partial x^{2}}$$

$$ \therefore \; \lambda S(x) = \gamma \cdot \frac{\partial^{2} S(x)}{\partial x^{2}} \Longrightarrow S_{k}(x) = sin(k \pi x) \Longrightarrow \lambda = - \gamma k^{2} \pi^{2}$$

$$ \therefore \; T(t, x) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} B_{k} e^{-\gamma k^{2} \pi^{2} t}S_{k}$$

---

What I did not understand was **why is there a** $k \pi$ **inside the** $sin$ **of** $S_{k}(x)$?

In my head, it would mean that imagining a rod has 10 meters of length, at $x = 0, x = 1, x = 2, x = 3, ... , x = 10$, the temperature would be 0, and that's insane to think about it because if I get a 10 meters rod right now and put a flame below these x points I will feel these points hot. How is temperature 0 at these points?

I have read once it was because of the boundary conditions but the temperature is being 0 not only at the beginning and the end of the rod but also in many points between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $k\pi$ comes from the assumption that the temperature is held at zero at both ends (at $x=0$ and $x=1$) plus the assumption that the solution is separable (a product of a function of $t$ and a function of $x$). This boundary condition type and the domain determine the eigenfunctions; with a different BC and/or domain you would have different eigenfunctions and indeed different dynamics.

The overall solution is only formed by summing over $k$. So the fact that some of the $S_k$ have interior zeros for those points at all times does not mean that the whole solution has zeros at those points, unless the initial condition was prepared as a multiple of $\sin(k\pi x)$ in the first place.

To get a feel for it, try computing the coefficients in the case where the initial condition is $T(x,0)=x-x^2$ and draw some plots.

Comment: I am sorry if I am misunderstanding your explanation sir, but let me give an example:

Let's consider T for a given integer $x$. For example, x = 1. T(t, 1) = $\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}B_{k}e^{- \gamma k^{2} \pi^{2}t}sin(k \pi)$. Throughout the summation of all integer $k$, isn't all the sines always going to be 0 because it's going to be multiples of $\pi$ ?

Comment: @VictorLins At $x=1$ yes, that is intentional because of the boundary condition. Physically it means you have an object at T=0 in perfect thermal contact with each end of the rod at all times. Keep in mind here that this derivation was also specific to the domain $[0,1]$. If you did it on $[0,2]$ and moved the boundary condition to $x=2$ then you would get different eigenfunctions.

Comment: Being x = arbitrary integer, isn't the angle inside the sine still going to multiples of $\pi$?

Comment: @VictorLins There are no integers in the interior of the domain $[0,1]$.

Comment: How can I see that this derivation was specific to the domain [0, 1]?

Comment: He seems to gloss over this detail earlier in the video and mentions it later. Maybe you need more context from earlier in the series to be clear that this is the case of interest, I dunno. I hadn't watched these previously.

Comment: I see. Thank you, sir, for all this effort trying to explain me, I will try to go deeper into it!

Answer (score 2):

The $\pi$ is just there for convenience.  If you leave it out you just rescale $x$.  The $k$ factor indexes the eigenfunctions.  There are $k$ half waves along the bar.  The heat equation washes out temperature differences.  The modes with large $k$ wash out more quickly because the curvature of the temperature is higher by a factor $k^2$.

This set of eigenfunctions assumes the temperature is zero at the ends of the bar.  If it were not, you would have to add in functions of the form $\cos (k \pi x)$ as well.

You can certainly have the temperature nonzero at points in the middle of the bar.  If you take $k$ to be an integer, as is usual, the length of the bar is $1$ (with the $\pi$ factor included) so the lowest mode is a half sine wave.  The point you are thinking of as $x=1$ on a $10$ meter bar is really $x=0.1$ because it is $\frac 1{10}$ of the way down the bar.  Many of the sine functions are nonzero at that point.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I had not the idea of this rescaling, which is insightful.